# spring, transaction and unit tests - how to set transaction on class level

Tags: unit-testing, spring, transactions, junit

I'm using Spring junit runner, and its transaction capabilities to start and rollback transactions before and after every test.

However I have a test class with some heavy DB initialization and I want each test (method) to run within the transaction scope, i.e. start a transaction at the beginning of the test and roll it back after all tests in the class completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are You aware that having all the test methods inside your class within a single transaction will cause a lot of trouble? Basically you can no longer depend on having a clean database as other test methods will modify it along the way. And because the order of test methods is not specified, you cannot depend on it as well (so you'll never know what exactly does the database hold). Essentially You are giving up all test transactional support, your only guarantee is that after running the whole test case, the database will remain clean (so other test cases won't be affected).

End of grumbling thou. I don't think Spring supports such a behavior out-of-the-box (partially due to the reasons highlighted above). However, if You look closely at [TransactionalTestExecutionListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html), it is responsible for transactional support in Spring-powered tests.

```
@Override
public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    //...
    startNewTransaction(testContext, txContext);
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    //...
    endTransaction(testContext, txContext);
    //...
}
```

Now look even closer, there are unimplemented `beforeTestClass` and `afterTestClass`... You will find detailed instructions how to wire this all up in chapter [9.3.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-framework) of Spring reference documentation. Hint: write your own listener and use it instead of `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`.